# Split a message in parts that contains a keyword - Python

Tags: python, split

I have a string like this in `Python`:

```
Customer 1:
Name: A
Address: B
Phone: XXXXXX

Customer 2:
Name: A2
Address: B2
Phone: YYYYYY
....
```

Is there a way to split my string into a container that each position is the information about the each `Customer`? I mean, split the message into parts using the keyword `Customer` for processing each one individually later?

Comment: Any code you've written?

Comment: wouldnt the best way to do this be making it a `CSV` and splitting on the comma?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint Because the info is given to me as I said...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### update

tested.

---

```
import re

parts = re.split(r'\s?Customer \d+:\s', inputStr.strip())[1:]

results = {}
for index, part in enumerate(parts):
    results["Customer %s" % (index)] = {e[0].strip() : e[1].strip() for e in [i.split(':') for i in part.strip().split('\n')]}
```

Comment: This works, but I don't know how to access the information about Customer i.

Comment: `print(results)` to see the results. you can access by `results["Customer num"]` such as `results["Customer 1"]`